# ggplot2 boxplot aligned plotting one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm struggling to graph a boxplot from a dataframe. I have a dataframe df which contains 3 columns: `df$A` , `df$B`, `df$C`.  I want to have `df$C` in the X-axis and plot `df$A` and `df$B` as boxplot on the Y-axis in one graph.  So, for each value of x-axis, it should be two values `df$A` and `df$B`.  I want to have the boxes are aligned for each value of X-axis (`df$C`). I have tried to use interaction to combine (`A`,`B`) in column then graph it like this:

```
df$AandB <- interaction(df$A, df$fB)

ggplot(aes(y = AandB, x = df$C), data = df) + geom_boxplot()
```

BUT it didn’t work. It showed me only horizontal lines-sorry I couldn't upload the image as I'm new user.

I found some suggestions to use fill or colour but it didn’t work.

Any suggestions?

sample of my df:

```
  A         B         C  
 200.12    30.11       28.75 
 100.75    26.17       29.98        
 27.33      25.58      34.98 
 25.19      22.6       35.56 
 40.03      21.02      37.51 
 20.3       18.31      44.75
```

Comment: Please provide some additional information on your data. What is the output of `str(df)`? Could you provide the output of `dput(df)`?

Comment: I have included the output df !!!

Comment: In your example data, each unique value of `C` has exactly one value for `A` and one value `B`. What kind of boxes are you looking for?

Comment: I want to plot for each unique value of C a box for A and B aligned to each other to show the difference. The boxes should include the value of the mean.

Answer (score 1):

The data:

```
df <- read.table(text="A         B         C  
200.12    30.11       28.75 
100.75    26.17       29.98        
27.33      25.58      34.98 
25.19      22.6       35.56 
40.03      21.02      37.51 
20.3       18.31      44.75", header = TRUE)
```

First, the data needs to be arranged in the long format. The values of `A` and `B` are combined in one column with the `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
df_l <- melt(df, id.vars = "C")
```

Now, the plot can be created:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_l, aes(x = C, y = value)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(group = C),
               fun.y = mean, fun.ymin = min, fun.ymax = max, geom = "crossbar")
```

The crossbar denotes both the range and the mean of the data.
[image]

Comment: It seems you plot both of A & B in one box plot. What I was looking for each single C value, two boxes: one for A and one for B besides each other(offset=0). Therefore, I would expect for the above data 12 boxes each two (box A and box B) will map to C value. Also, I need to add legend and color for each of trend (A,B). In order to reduce offset between boxes, I think I can use geom_jitter (geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0)) ).